# How makes last-child in ng-repeat in AngularJs hidden?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use ng-repeat in my code.

```
<span ng-repeat="provide in user.profiles">
  <span ng-switch on="provide.provider">
     <span ng-switch-when="google" class="color-google">GOOGLE</span>
     <span ng-switch-when="yahoo" class="color-tinet">YAHOO</span>
  </span>
  <span> - </span>
</span>
```

How can I hide the last hyphen?
Is there a way to hide the last item in ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1):

$last shows the last item in ng-repeat.

```
<span ng-repeat="provide in user.profiles">
  <span ng-switch on="provide.provider">
     <span ng-switch-when="google" class="color-google">GOOGLE</span>
     <span ng-switch-when="yahoo" class="color-tinet">YAHOO</span>
  </span>
  <span ng-if="!$last"> - </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ng-hide` directive with the `$last` special property:

```
<span ng-repeat="provide in user.profiles">
  <span ng-switch on="provide.provider">
     <span ng-switch-when="google" class="color-google">GOOGLE</span>
     <span ng-switch-when="yahoo" class="color-tinet">YAHOO</span>
  </span>
  <span ng-hide="$last"> - </span>
</span>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-hide Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)
- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Special Properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview)